# How to force apt-get to install the latest version from the fontforge repository

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Complete Linux noobie that I am, I can't seem to get `apt-get` to install the latest version of `font-forge`.

Background: I'm running the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10 and even got GUI applications running using Xming Server. Yes, I could run a VM, but I felt like I'd just give it a try as a proof-of-concept. Anyway, I don't think it has to do with my real issue, I just thought I'd mention my setup just in case.

The Ubuntu version I'm running is `18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)`. I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, everything is up-to-date.

So I followed the [fontforge installation instructions for Ubuntu](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Installing_Fontforge.html) and ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fontforge/fontforge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontforge
```

This installed fontforge, and it does open and show up, but the issue is that it's an old version: `1:20170731~dfsg-1`.

The command `fontforge -v` shows

```
...
 Based on sources from 11:21 UTC 24-Sep-2017-ML-D.
 Based on source from git with hash:
no xdefs_filename!
...
fontforge 11:21 UTC 24-Sep-2017
libfontforge 20170924
```

[This page](https://launchpad.net/%7Efontforge/+archive/ubuntu/fontforge) lists `20190413-27-g1acfefa-0ubuntu1~bionic` as the latest version for Bionic, but it also states "(Newer version available)" next to it and links to [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontforge/1:20170731%7Edfsg-1), which seems to say that the version from the Ubuntu default repositories is treated as being newer than that from the fontforge repo. I'm confused as to why this is the case, and I would like to tell `apt-get` to install the other, more recent version.

I guess the safest path would be to compile from source, as the version in the fontforge repo seems quite some time behind, but I'd really prefer not having to do that.

---

as requested, the output of `apt-cache policy fontforge`:

```
apt-cache policy fontforge
fontforge:
  Installed: 1:20170731~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1:20170731~dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:20170731~dfsg-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20190413-27-g1acfefa-0ubuntu1~bionic 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fontforge/fontforge/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 3):

The `1:` at the start of the version in the Ubuntu repositories (known as the epoch) causes `apt` to consider that version as newer than the version in the PPA. To install the latter, you need to ask `apt` to do so explicitly:

```
sudo apt install fontforge=20190413-27-g1acfefa-0ubuntu1~bionic
```

You’ll then need to put a hold on it, or add a pin priority on the PPA, to prevent `apt` from “upgrading” the package to the version in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-mark hold fontforge
```

Comment: The first command results in `E: Release '20190413-27-g1acfefa-0ubuntu1~bionic' for 'fontforge' was not found` for me

Comment: Never mind, must have had a typo or something. Now it's complaining about "unmet dependencies" that are not going to be installed. I'm trying to install those manually right now

Comment: That did the trick! I guess I'll need to use `apt-mark` on the dependencies as well? And how would I check for updates and update from the other repository in the future?

Comment: I don’t think you would need holds on the dependencies; once `fontforge` is installed, it will constrain them appropriately. Using a hold means you’ll have to check for upgrades manually; pin priorities would be better (but I can’t check the required configuration just now). Of course the best solution for everyone would be for the PPA to use an epoch too ;-).